# Does Freedom of Movement allow movement while melded into stone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

If someone is melded into stone under the *meld into stone spell*, can they cast *freedom of movement* on themselves and walk through the stone?

Comment: For clarity, are you actually asking if someone who has melded into stone can cast freedom of movement, or are you asking if being under the effect of FoM allows you to move while melded into stone (such as having a friend that can cast it before you go into the stone)?  [This answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/190750/62294) shows that you cannot actually cast it while in the stone, but I'm not sure that was actually what you were looking for.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Freedom of Movement states:

> For the duration, the target's movement is unaffected by difficult terrain, and spells and other magical effects can neither reduce the target's speed nor cause the target to be paralyzed or restrained.

Meld into Stone states:

> You can use your movement to leave the stone where you entered it, which ends the spell. **You otherwise can't move.**

Meld into Stone does not count as difficult terrain, does not reduce the target's speed and does not cause the creature to become paralyzed or retrained. These are all specific game mechanic terms with their own rules.

**Meld into Stone simply specifies that you cannot move, thus Freedom of Movement has no affect on them.**

Answer (score 20):

### You can’t move

I agree with the conclusion of [Purple Monkey's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/190738/62294), but I disagree with the reasoning, hence the separate answer.

The reason why you can’t move in the stone isn’t because *Meld Into Stone* says you cannot move; It’s because it doesn’t say you *can*. Not being able to move isn’t an effect of *Meld Into Stone*, it’s merely a reminder that nothing about the spell gives you the ability to move around in stone. So since neither *Meld Into Stone* nor *Freedom Of Movement* give you the ability to move through stone other in the very limited capacity the former spell specifies, no combination of the spells results in it either.

If we had a hypothetical spell called *Restriction of Movement* that simply said “the target cannot move”, then *Freedom Of Movement* would absolutely let you ignore that - it’s a poorly written spell perhaps, but the only ways this spell could be interpreted in game mechanical terms is that it reduces your speed to 0 and *possibly* applies *Restrained* or maybe even *Paralyzed*, all of which of course *Freedom of Movement* guards against. Conditions aren’t a one way street - you can’t say someone is incapacitated but not *Incapacitated*, you can’t say *you are physically restricted from moving* without also implying *Restrained*. It’s just that in the cited example it’s not the spell that’s restraining you, it’s the stone that the spell let you move into as an *exception* to the general expectation that moving through stone is not something you can do (*Freedom of Movement* or not).

Answer (score 3):

You can't naturally move through stone, so FoM isn't going to help you here even if the DM ruled MiS couldn't do anything to it.

FoM protects you from harsh terrain and spells that would hinder your movement. *Meld Into Stone* doesn't hinder your movement, nor does it let you burrow through stone to your heart's content. It melds *you specifically* into the stone so that you can hide. In addition, you can move! The spell specifies quite clearly your movement is unimpeded where the spell affects the stone, the spot you came in.

The other parts of the stone are still just rock, and FoM acts the way it normally does with rock. It's not harsh terrain, it's impassable terrain. Meld into Stone does not give you the burrow ability, nor does it give you the ability to move through rock.

It only gives you the ability to meld into it.

So while the wording is poor and invites this discussion, ultimately the specific vs general rule is the wrong way to look at this in my opinion, because it's just going to come down to who can convince the DM their spell has the specific over-riding words, which can be applied either way, both, based on spell level, etc.

Answer (score -4):

### You can't cast Freedom of Movement while melded

Meld to stone specifies that you can cast spells while melded, but can't move except to leave the stone. Freedom of Movement requires Verbal, Somatic and Material components, but Somatic components are literally hand motions (to the point that they can be inhibited by armor), so unless you have a way to cast without the Somatic components of a spell you won't be able to cast Freedom of Movement.

Comment: "You touch a willing creature." Just have a friend that can cast it.

Comment: You can't be seen or touched while you're melded in the stone, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: ...have them cast it before you go into the stone. It has a duration of one hour.

Comment: I see the confusion, gonna ask OP to clarify.

Comment: TBF I think Purple Monkey's answer is the correct one, I mainly wanted to point out the explicit prevention of movement (aside from leaving) prohibits any spell with a somatic component (and possibly verbal or material as well depending on your DM)

Comment: You could also just cast FoM on yourself before you cast meld into stone, neither requires concentration. I really don't think the actual casting in that specific order is what OP was actually asking about.